# Getting Platform info of iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can one get iPhone system information such as sdk version? 
The information I need is similar to the device information you see when your iphone/itouch is connected to itunes.
I can use UniqueDevice to get the serial number but cant seem to find any system properties or request methods in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the UIDevice class - that's pretty much all you're going to get from the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

i think by SDK you mean the system version...so check
[UIDevice systemVersion](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/systemVersion)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I must be blind, they were right infront of my eyes all along.
Here is the code I'm using to get data I need.

serial_no = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
system = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];